# input a value and check it with a value in database laravel

Tags: laravel

how to  add a value to input form and that value compares with an ID in a table in Database and if exist return Back the data of that row of the id
I'm using laravel collective .but i didn't know how to check the value from input in store method.

Comment: What attempt have you made?

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel's validation. In your controller, for example, let's say you are creating a new product, and you want to ensure that the product's `sku` is unique in the database.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'sku' => 'required|unique:products,sku',
    ]);
    //... your other code runs if the 'sku' field is unique (does not exist already).
}
```

The first value after the `unique` rule is the table, e.g. `products` followed by the column to check `sku`. If the `sku` already exists, Laravel will kick back with a validation error, otherwise it will proceed. [Read more about Laravel validation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation).